# Bent and hyper-bent functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, cr.crypto-security, boolean-functions

Is the AND logic function considered to be a [bent function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_function)? If it is, how could one make a hyper-bent funtion using logic gates? Thank you (two questions in one: very efficient :) )

Comment: Very inefficient: wrong site. ;-P (At least, I don't see the, uhm, connection ;-))

Comment: Owen, this question is probably more appropriate for stackoverflow.com, or perhaps cstheory.stackexchange.com I'm not sure how likely you are to get an answer here.

Comment: [Crosspost in math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20978/2767).

Comment: The link is added after the revision. Currently the question is too basic, since it can be answered by the wiki article. See [the FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Claude Carlet in a private email. The AND function is bent as long as it has only two variables.